# Adding to a property in a restful API

Tags: api, http, rest

I am in the process of designing an HTTP API.

I have a Card resource which has an Balance property, which clients can add/subtract to.

At first I thought this should be implemented as PUT, because it's a form of Update to the resource, but then I read that PUT is idempotent, but adding to an amount isn't idempotent.

As it's not a creation of an object, I think I'm left with referring to it as a controller, something like:

```
POST example.org/card/{card-Id}/AddToBalance

data: value=10
```

will add 10 to the balance.

**Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 1):

Yea, use cases like these are not where REST excels (expressing operations, particularly when they only affect a small subset of an entities data). Your particular case is pretty simple though, you can handle it with a slight change to your verb and endpoint:

```
PUT example.org/card/{card-Id}/balance

{"value" : 100}
```

Basically read as `"Update the balance of card {id} to 100"`. On the server side you will still need to validate the transaction, and determine wether its a valid add based off the existing value of the balance.

Comment: In your example if someone has 120 before it means he wants so withdraw 20 and if he has 80 it means he wants to deposit 20? That's problematic, if the value was changed from a different source...

Comment: So, in this example the client is requesting the balance for a card to be set to 100. The server retrieves the current balance, which if its 80, determines that this is a request to add 20 to the balance. Whereas is the current balance is 120 then the request is to withdraw 20 from the balance.

Comment: Important points to remember, when treating changes to the balance as an idempotent operation, the server must determine wether the effective change to the balance is a deposit or withdrawal, and wether its allowed for the calling client.

Comment: I think this approach may cause some problems, first, a client needs to retrieve the balance, making it two calls instead of one. second, if a client retrieved the balance, and it's 80, and the client wants to add 20, it will call 100, but what if a second client already updates it to 200, then the cal actually removes 100...

Answer (score 0):

Design Looks good  as for as REST principals are concerned.

PUT action should be Idempotent. But it depends upon you requirement

Other thing you can use **PATCH**, as you are just doing partial amount of Updates rather than complete replacement of resources.

Comment: Can you suggest a more suitable approach? I'm having trouble understanding your first sentence, please explain what you meant